# Using react-date http://airbnb.io/react-dates

Tags: reactjs, npm

I use this npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dates

and I do

```
import { SingleDatePicker } from 'react-dates';
and in my render function I do

<SingleDatePicker id="date" />
```

...that is it, and it worked. I tried to change SingleDatePicker to its second API and ccording to the doc, it's `DateRangePicker`. I can see it got rendered, but when I click it it does nothing. I have no clue what's wrong, there's no error in my console.

Comment: Are you sure you have imported DateRangePicker from 'react-dates'?

Comment: @squGEIm very sure because as I said SingleDatePicker  will worked.

Answer (score 0):

The [react-dates README](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates) lists the required props and their type for the `SingleDatePicker` component:

```
<SingleDatePicker
  date={this.state.date} // momentPropTypes.momentObj or null
  onDateChange={date => this.setState({ date })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired
  focused={this.state.focused} // PropTypes.bool
  onFocusChange={({ focused }) => this.setState({ focused })} // PropTypes.func.isRequired
/>
```

To handle user interaction, you must supply a function to the onFocusChanged and a bool to the focused prop (as shown above). With the implementation above, you would just need to add an inital `focused` value to your state.

ie. `state = {... focused: false}`

Be aware you will need to use the [moment](https://momentjs.com) package to prodive the date objects to the `date` prop.